# How to send xml file with post request in JMeter

Tags: xml, http-post, jmeter

I am using JMeter 2.13 . I am sending xml as attachment in Post request

> Parameters **authenticity_token** :- hjghjsdfhjghsjkdg, **utf8** :- ✓
>
> HTTP Header Manager :- **Accept** : text/xml, C**ontent Type**:- text/xml
>
> **Port** 80 , **Method** Post, **Protocol** http

I am adding file address as in attachement

> System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "NewXMLEvent.xml"

I want to send xml as file rather than parameter or body, this xml file is created with code, its not working ,
Do I need to add any other header info, or data

response I am getting is `XML content expected`

Comment: Did you try to read that file content as a variable and add that variable to the request's body? It worked for me as far as I remember.

Comment: file have about 1000 lines of code. its will not work !

Answer (score 1):

Your approach won't work.

If you need to **upload** a file -  valid values are:

1. Full path to the file (recommended)
2. Relative path to the file
3. JMeter Property which is set during JMeter launch or via user.properties file

---

If you need to **send XML file content**:

1. Switch to "Body Data" tab
2. Use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function to specify source XML file location

   [image: FiletoString function example]

You can even combine __FileToString() function with [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function to dynamically get the file path like:

```
${__FileToString(${__BeanShell(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "NewXMLEvent.xml",)},,)}
```

I know, the syntax is scary, that's why I use [Function Helper Dialog](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) for generating functions.

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on above and other useful JMeter functions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above three steps posted in Answer 1 and none of them actually worked. I am testing a REST API.

My XML file has about 5000 lines, so it would be convenient if I could just point do 1. above the full path to file. However, this did not work. I also had three other parameters, other than the one called content and had to supply the value.

In JMeter 3.0, with Method as POST, under Parameters I supplied:
param1 value1
param2 value2
param3 value3
For content, I opened the XML file with an Editor and then Select All, then Copy.
In JMeter for Value->Detail - This opens up an scratch pad. Paste XML content in that.
Just for content, I checked Encoding and Equals.

This way I was able to send my XML file. Hope this works for others as well